# ServiceStack Redis Client Bulk Insert using Pipelining

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I have to insert ~80,000 rows into redis at one time and was looking into using redis pipelining to do so. However when testing on inserting only 1000 rows it is taking 46 seconds with pipelining vs 6 seconds without pipelining.

In the code below I have a list of zipcodes grouped by zipcode that I am trying to insert into redis. They are being inserted in as a RedisZipCode that contains the zipcode as id and the list of zipcodes that were gathered during the grouping.

```
public class ZipCode
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zip_code { get; set; }
}

public class RedisZipCode
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCode> zipcodes{ get; set; }
}
```

**Without Pipelining**

```
using (var zipCodeClient = redisClient.GetTypedClient<RedisZipCode>())
{
    foreach (var item in zipcodes.GroupBy(z => z.zip_code))
    {
        zipCodeClient.Store(new RedisZipCode(item.ToList()));
    }
}
```

**With Pipelining**

```
using (var zipCodeClient = redisClient.GetTypedClient<RedisZipCode>())
using (var pipeline = zipCodeClient.CreatePipeline())
{
    foreach (var item in zipcodes.GroupBy(z => z.zip_code))
    {
        pipeline.QueueCommand(c => c.Store(new RedisZipCode(item.ToList())));
    }
    pipeline.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Are these benchmark results testing against a local redis-server instance? if they are, what are the numbers vs a remote redis-server?

Comment: Those benchmarks are for a local redis-server instance. When running against a remote server the times were 3 seconds for non-pipelining and it did not finish when using pipelining. It was running with pipelining for over 6 minutes and just kept running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697389/why-it-is-so-slow-with-100-000-records-when-using-pipeline-in-redis Don't forget the buffer size of your packages. Test it with more pipline operations