# Redis pipelining

Tags: perl, redis

I would like to take advantage of client pipelining when populating database. How can I achieve this using [perl Redis client](http://search.cpan.org/~dams/Redis-1.972/lib/Redis.pm)?

```
use Redis;

my $redis = Redis->new or die "No redis server";

$redis->multi;
for my $i (1 .. 20000) {

  $redis->set("key.$i" => "foo" x500);
}
$redis->exec;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Redis#PIPELINING) says you need to add a coderef to as the third argument to `set`.

> To use pipelining, add a coderef argument as the last argument to a command method call

That would turn your example into:

```
for my $i (1 .. 20000) {
  $redis->set("key.$i" => "foo" x500, sub {});
}
```

Instead of the empty sub, you can actually do stuff to the reply:

> The coderef you supply to a pipelined command method is invoked once
>   the response is available. It takes two arguments, $reply and $error.
>   If $error is defined, it contains the text of an error reply sent by
>   the Redis server. Otherwise, $reply is the non-error reply. For almost
>   all commands, that means it's undef, or a defined but non-reference
>   scalar, or an array ref of any of those; but see "keys", "info", and
>   "exec".

It also says in the [transaction handling](https://metacpan.org/pod/Redis#Transaction-handling-commands) part of the doc:

> Warning: the behaviour of these commands when combined with pipelining is still under discussion, and you should NOT use them at the same time just now.

Comment: But I've got the feeling you read all this already and looking for something else.

Comment: Tnx for reply, yes I've read this and it looks confusing a bit. So it suggests that transaction should be dropped when pipe-lining. Another thing that bothers me [how long is pipeline and should I worry about it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16710211/223226)?

Comment: That link answer is very interesting. Not sure what you are trying to do, though. Sounds like you just have to be careful how much data you put in at one time. But I believe it heavily depends on the power of the box. They are talking about 6MB of data. To my setup, that is virtually nothing even for sending over network internally. So I'd say we'd have to look at the circumstances of your task. But I agree, it says you should not do transactions. A pipeline is very similar to a transaction anyway, isn't it? The difference is where the commands are collected.

Comment: I have scheduled job which fills new values, and I thought to speed it up by using pipe line. Resources are there to support that, but I would not like to clog redis or something.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Do you need the transaction? Maybe benchmark both solutions.

Comment: This is a good question, and it seems that transaction can be dropped in favor of speedier job.