# How to improve Read performance in redis

Tags: redis, jedis

I have around 3 million keys of structure
with following format as an example

```
3000000:60
```

Each key has a hset of string converted values of integer and double

Each key has around 10 such entries in map.

```
Key: String = 3000000:60

Value : field(String) = abcc , Value = 1000:-123.456:1001:234.57:.....
```

When I read the data using `hgetAll` or `hget` or `hmget` it takes 2-3 minutes

When I change it to pipeline , I could finish in 20 seconds but I am not sure how to process the data in batches.

My code snippet is like below

```
readPipeline.multi();

for (long i = start; i < end; ++i)

  if (pipelineBatch == currentBatchCount)

     readPipeline.exec();

     List<Object> allObjects = readPipeline.syncAndReturnAll();
```

Here when I read sometimes the Objects have value as Queued. So, how do I process the pipelined data?

Comment: You should add some more information about how you're doing it and the setup that you're using. Advice such as reduce network latency, use threads, pipelining and similar are of little value without more background.

Comment: @Haber I am running on 4GB Windows machine , Server and Clients both are on same machine. I am using 10 client sessions in 10 different threads. each thread has one client connection.

Comment: this is how my code look likes for read , for (long i = start; i < end; ++i)
           keyReadSession.hgetAll(i + ":60");

Comment: Use pipelining to batch your hgetall. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697389/why-it-is-so-slow-with-100-000-records-when-using-pipeline-in-redis/16710211#16710211

Comment: @Spezia I have seen this , this is for for set , but I am not sure how to achieve the pipeline in get request.

Comment: I have updated my keys and question , please refer the question again

Comment: Your code doesn't have get(), could you post your actual code to Gist and link it?